# WSO2 API-Manager - Is it possible create a tenat under a tenat?

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I'm trying to create tenant under a tenant. Is it possible so implement something like this in WSO2 Api manager?

[Sample Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54aaH.png)

Or multiple super tenants, each super tenat have tenants under it. But, super tenat-1 cannot access super tenat-2's child tenats. You can find sample diagram below.

[Sample Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64T7s.png)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

1. No
2. No

You can only have one super tenant(carbon.super). Only that tenant can create sub tenants. A tenant is a logically separated data collection from other tenants.